# Is it possible to play music stored on a node.js server in the client's browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, raspberry-pi2

I have a large database of audio files (a mixture of .mp3 and .m4a files) which I would like to store on a Raspberry pi. Would it be possible using node.js to create a web server which would allow me to connect to the pi from another device and play the audio files on the server from within a browser? Is this even possible and if so then which modules would I need to download?

Thanks, Mitra0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be pretty simple using python and nodejs. First lets assume that `192.168.0.1` is the server, and `192.168.0.2` is the computer with the music files.

### Start the python server

What you will do is on the computer with the music files, you will `cd /folder/with/music` then start a python server `python -m http.server 8000` (or `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` for python2)

### Explanation of nodejs server

now you can run your node server on the other computer. When you want to use a file for your server, just use `http://192.168.0.2:8000/file/you/want.mp3` instead of `/path/to/local/file.mp3`.

### Nodejs server code

The below code is an example of a basic node express server that will play music. This should be on the server. Not the computer with the audio files on it.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var musicPath = "http://192.168.0.2:8000/helloWorld.mp3"; //change this path to your music file.
var onclickHTML = "var audio = new Audio('" + musicPath + "'); audio.play();"
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('<button onclick="' + onclickHTML + '">click me to hear music</button>'); //this creates a button that the user can click to play some audio.
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Hope this helps! feel free to ask any follow up question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what would the code for the python HTTP server look like? Thanks.

Comment: That is built into Python, you don't have to code anything for the Python server

Comment: I tried writing "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" in cmd in the target folder and it returned: "C:\Python34\python.exe: No module named SimpleHTTPServer"

Comment: Oh, sorry, you should type: `python -m http.server 8000`. It changes because you are using python3

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you please up vote it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the late reply. This works brilliantly for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!